# How to debug action extension crash with Photo host on device rotation

Tags: ios, action

I have an action extension that crashes reproducably when called from the Photos app as host, as soon as I rotate the device but without any notice why or anything. I also do not find anything in the console. It simply disappears and the debugger stops. When I call the extension from another host like Safari or the Files app, it does not crash on device rotation. The phone is an iPhone7 with iOS 13.3.1 but it does not crash in the simulator with iOS 13.3. Tried to restart the phone but it didn't change anything, still crashes.
How can I debug this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution for the action extension crash with the photo app as host. It goes away if I override  `- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask) supportedInterfaceOrientations`